# Variable scope difference between PHP and C: block scope is not exactly the same?

Tags: php, c, scope

The following PHP code will output `3`.

```
function main() {
    if (1) {
        $i = 3;
    }
    echo $i;
}

main();
```

But the following C code will raise a compile error.

```
void main() {
    if (1) {
        int i = 3;
    }

    printf("%d", i);
}
```

So variables in PHP are not strictly block-scoped? In PHP, variables defined in inner block can be used in outer block?

Comment: This isn't really a question if you've already answered it yourself.

Comment: @Byron - I just want to confirm this. It is weird to me who came to PHP from C.

Comment: why downvoting? i think question is fine

Comment: its encouraged to answer your own questions. You could raise a question with an answer (need to post it an answer though) as a form of knowledge sharing as http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 60, accepted):

PHP only has function scope - control structures such as `if` don't introduce a new scope. However, it also doesn't mind if you use variables you haven't declared. `$i` won't exist outside of `main()` or if the if statement fails, but you can still freely echo it.

If you have PHP's error_reporting set to include notices, it will emit an `E_NOTICE` error *at runtime* if you try to use a variable which hasn't been defined. So if you had:

```
function main() {
 if (rand(0,1) == 0) {
  $i = 3;
 }
 echo $i;
}
```

The code would run fine, but some executions will echo '3' (when the `if` succeeds), and some will raise an `E_NOTICE` and echo nothing, as `$i` won't be defined in the scope of the echo statement.

Outside of the function, `$i` will never be defined (because the function has a different scope).

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Good explanation! but just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. It's bad practice to use a variable that hasn't been defined.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to check if the result of the rand call is equal to zero. You can simply put a shebang before rand :)