# How to declare local variable inside a block which is invisible outside the block in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and already had some experience in Perl/C/Scheme, I find it bothering me that I 
don't know how to define variables inside blocks such as if/for/while and make it invisible outside the block.

Do I have to put the code inside a block into a function to make it local?

for example, a lot of my bugs were caused by code like this:

```
<?php
    for($id = 0; $id<10; $id++)
    {
        $a = $id;
    }
    if(1)
    {
        $b = 3;
    }
    echo $a;//9
    echo $id;//10;
    echo $b;//3
?>
```

However, I perl, such code will be safe:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
for(my $id = 0; $id < 10; $id++)
{
    my $a = $id;
}
if(1)
{
    my $b = 3;
}
#say $a; #error
#say $b; #error
#say $id; #error
```

and in C, such code will cause err(compile using -std=gnu99)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int a = i;
    }
    if(1)
    {
        int b = 3;
    }
    //printf("%d\n",i);//err
    //printf("%d\n",a);//err
    //printf("%d\n",b);//err
    return 0;
}
```

so, How could I avoid bugs because of the fact that PHP lacks block scope?

Comment: Cut your blocks into functions so it has a scope ? The best you can do is use some workarounds

Comment: By changing the way you think when you're coding: PHP !== Perl && PHP !== C

Comment: By keeping your functions and thereby your scope small and not reusing variable names within your scope for different purposes and initialising your variables at the top of the scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable scope difference between PHP and C: block scope is not exactly the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894087/variable-scope-difference-between-php-and-c-block-scope-is-not-exactly-the-same)

Comment: But How to avoid those bugs? if I define a variable, do I have to search the whole file and all the included file to make sure that it has not been set? or do I have to use functions?

Comment: If your scope is so expansive that you have to search several different files, your scope is simply too large.

Comment: to FuzzyTree: Actually I'm not asking about how to avoid bugs because of this feature of PHP, the only way I think is practical is using function, but I think it is kind of ugly..

Comment: If you are writing long procedural scripts, then there is your problem, either break it down into smaller functions, or follow an OOP approach, and you wont have this issue

Answer (score 2):

Several possible approaches, but they pretty much all boil down to this: break up your code into functions. One way or the other it all comes back to that. And regardless of PHP's lack of block scopes, you should do this anyway for maintainable and reusable code.

1. Use classes with methods as small and self contained as possible.
2. Use functions as small and self contained as possible.
3. Never use `global`.
4. Don't write long procedural code, regardless of whether it's within a function or not. If a scope is longer than one screen of code, chances are it's too long and can be broken down.
5. Use sane, descriptive variable names, initialise them at the top of each scope, and don't reuse them for different purposes throughout your scope.
6. Think more in terms of mapping operations, iterators and callbacks, e.g.:

   ```
   // Look ma, no $i or other superfluous iterator variables!
   $foo = array_map(function ($bar) { return /* something */; }, $baz);

   $foo = array_reduce($bar, function ($foo, $baz) { return /* something */; });

   $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
       new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
           new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__),
           function ($file) { return /* something */; }
       )
   );
   foreach ($files as $file) {
       /* A lot of code that would have gone here is in the
          RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator callback now. */
   }
   ```

Generally the sanest PHP code you'll see these days uses dependency injected OOP extensively and consists of many small classes with many small methods. This maximises code reusability, flexibility and reduces problems.

As a sort of ugly hackaround, you can artificially introduce scopes by emulating the common Javascript practice of IIFEs:

```
$foo = call_user_func(function () {
    /* your variables here */
    return $result;
});
```

This may be something for one-off scripts which essentially are just long and procedural but you nonetheless want to segregate by scope. I wouldn't really recommend that practice in general though.

Answer (score 0):

By using `unset($var);` at the end of each block.

Comment: using this way, I can only make sure tha my variable won't pollute other's but I can't be sure that my variable won't be polluted by other people...

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty anoying in PHP and personally I had a lot of bugs connected with this issue.

One way you can do it is to unset() variable in the end of block. So in your code do something like

```
<?php
    for($id = 0; $id<10; $id++)
    {
    $a = $id;
    }
    if(1)
    {
        $b = 3;
        unset($b);
    }
    echo $a;//9
    echo $id;//10;
    echo $b;//unset notice
?>
```

or assign null to variable before using it.

Comment: actually this is the method I use, if(isset($var)){die("errmsg")}...unset($var)...

Comment: You didnt use unset()